# Javascript Empty check

Tags: javascript, is-empty

So, i have this code but something doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["reg"]["username","password","first_name","last_name","age","mail"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="" || x==0) {
        alert("All fields must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get an alert if I leave any of the fields empty. Except for the last one. If I fill in every field except for mail, I can proceed. And if I only fill in mail, I can proceed as well.

How come it checks all the fields except the last one?

Or might there be an easier way to check if the fields are filled in? (I'm actually using PHP but somehow the `if(empty($_POST['username'])` thing doesn't work anymore, so I figured to just use JS, since it looks better with the alert message anyway.

Comment: And why the hell do people give me -1 on my question? would like to know what i'm doing wrong if it's not up to your standards...

Comment: @George Well, it does. I can leave all the previous fields empty and i get an alert message everytime. Except for the mail field. It doesn't give me a alert message if i leave that one empty or only fill in the mail field.

Comment: The code is technically valid, but it doesn't do what you think it does. The first line of the function is effectively just `var x = document.forms.reg.mail.value;` - it only really checks one field.

Comment: Also: value can not be null so that check is useless.

Comment: Client side validation is just for better UX. You have to do server side validation either way.

Comment: @Xereoth many people here at StackOverflow like to give -1 instead of providing proper answer.. they are among senior folks here and they do not want others to get senior or earn more badges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break your function up a little bit - put the field names into an array and loop through them one by one. And as stated in the comments, the null check isn't required.

```
function validateForm()
{
    var fields = ["username", "password", "first_name", "last_name", "age", "mail"];
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
    {
        var fieldName = fields[i];
        var x = document.forms["reg"][fieldName].value;
        if (x == "" || x == 0) {
            alert("All fields must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You should also do the same validation in your PHP code, as someone could easily disable JavaScript and so the data wouldn't get validated at all.

Comment: Genius! I am trying my best at programming but somehow i just can't think of things like this by myself... I always try it too difficult or too easy.. your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the whole thing in an array! Instead you need to do it differently. It takes only the `mail` one as that's the last one in the list. So, you can do something like this:

```
x = [];
x.push(document.forms["reg"]["username"].value);
x.push(document.forms["reg"]["password"].value);
x.push(document.forms["reg"]["first_name"].value);
x.push(document.forms["reg"]["last_name"].value);
x.push(document.forms["reg"]["age"].value);
x.push(document.forms["reg"]["mail"].value);
```

And that you have built that array, you need to check for `""` and `0` values in them. You need to write a function like `in_array()` of PHP to JavaScript to check for empty and `0` values.

Instead of all these hassles, you can happily use a jQuery form validator plugin, and it does the work well.